# How to open an application again from URL Scheme iPhone

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, url-scheme

I am trying to implement URL Schemes in my iPhone.

Actually i Want to open a transaction page in my iPhone application. It opens in some browser lets say i opened http:www.xxxx.com. Now it has some php code written at backend. There is a submit button. I submit , it process the php code and do obtain some response.

Now I want to open the application again and get that response. How can I call my application from my php code of that webpage I called and pass that response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must add url scheme in your application. Go in Xcode to your target -> info->URL Types and create an url scheme like "myapp". In your app delegate implement the -`canOpenUrl...` method and return yes when you want your app to launch.

On your php side, you will need to tell the browser to open the address myapp://dataTopasstoYourApplicationThatYouCanParseInTheCanOpenURLMethodInYourAppDelegate

basically you do this with some javascript like `location.somethingIDontRemember... = myapp://...` or in PHP with header location

```
<?php
header('Location: myapp://whatYouWant');
exit;
?>
```

Comment: yes i know but how can i call this url from my php code i mean

Comment: see it's not harder than this

Comment: so once i complete my processing and have variable $response as resposne i call header('Location: myapp://whatYouWant'); and how to pass that response

Comment: in the url! you must url encode your $response in the url into json string or base64 encoded string. and parse it on the other side. myapp://{json:12,house:22,else:nothing}